# Update mysql table with a click of dropdownlist in the view

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

Can someone please help me i want to update a database record by using the dropdownlistbox,
so when i select an option from the dropdown the database is updated with that value for that record, without having to click a submit button using codeigniter.

I know the best way to go about this is with AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Yeah AJAX can make it work, and doing it with jQuery can make it a lot easier. You can add an event listener to your dropdown list, listening to a change in its value:

```
$("#the-dropdown-list").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr("value");
  $.ajax({
    url: "path/to/controller/action/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {value: value},
    success: function() {
      // whatever you want to do after
    }
  });
});
```

This will detect a change in the dropdown list value, and then send it to the controller action given in `url` in `$.ajax` object. After that you can just update the database record like you would usually do. In the controller, the new value can be obtained using `$_POST['value']`, since we defined `type` to be `POST` and the different values to be passed to controller action are in the `data`.